# handling collision between objects

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I'm trying to implement the dynamic of the interaction between a tugboat and a ship during the pushing phase.
The graphic engine that I'm using is able to detect collision and to give the normal vector in the collision point. I have to determine the dynamic knowing the forces acting on the boats.
I'm not able to deny to boats to go one inside the other.
Does somebody have any idea on how to manage this problem or do you know a good book where the issue is handled?
Thank you.

Comment: If there is a collision, then one boat will 'go inside the other' if you assume that the hulls are not infinitely stiff - the hulls will deform.  Hopefully, this deformation is elastic as the alternative tends to cause pilots/masters to explode violently.  This is more a dynamic physics and materials science issue than software development and you question will prolly get closed.

Comment: if you mean simply the visual 'blending' of the two 3d objects, what you have to do is limit the coordinates of the striker so that it cannot pass inside the struck object: just bound the maximum nearest distance so that the 2 objects merely touch and they will appear to collide and be indestructible( well at the most basic level at least).